# postgres restore with psql fails

Tags: postgresql, restore

I'm having what should be a simple task that is failing. I have some friends in Africa who are literally dependent on me getting this DB back online. The problem started when the power surged (Its central Africa - no surprise) and the production DB didn't want to come back up. It had a "failed to re-find parent key in index ..."

I was forced to do a pg_resetxlog as their backup didn't work. (Always the case when you need it most!)

After bringing up the db with pg_resetxlog, I did an immediate pg_dumpall to a target file. Previous to this pg_resetxlog I tarballed the entire postgres directories off to another target.

The pg_dumpall worked fine.

I dropped the database in question, then did a vacuum analyze on the only remaining postgres db several times. There wasn't much in there and the db could successfully start and stop with this it.

I then recreated the db from dump script then ran a:

```
psql -f dumpfile.sql
```

It restores the schema objects fine for the db. It gets about 43GB into the 50GB target when it just seems to fail.

Then only indication I have is from the postgres log:

```
checkpoints are occurring too frequently ...
could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
unexpected EOF on client connection
```

Its Postgres 8.4 on Ubuntu 10.04

The situation is truly an emergency as those folks I'm trying to help are actually in jeopardy, no kidding as this is a government db and its, well Africa.

Comment: Are you running `psql` on the same machine where the Postgres server is running? "*could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer*" is typically  a sign of a network problem.

Comment: Yes I am. I initially thought that the problem was a timeout so I did it again as a screen session and again with it just running as a bg (ctl-z bg). Both had the same results.

Comment: You could try to set `tcp_keepalives_idle` to a non-zero value (and possibly `tcp_keepalives_interval`, too)

Comment: Note: on most systems `bg` does not prevent the program/shell from getting a SIGHUP on a broken connection/ terminnal line. use `nohup` for that.

Comment: I've now tried with tcp keepalive settings and no help. I'm also trying with a nohup right now

Comment: Sadly the nohup didn't help either. It quit at the same 43 GB. which makes me wonder if the file has a problem or if I need to do a initdb?

Comment: Did you use the nohup at the *remote* machine? (you do need shell access) And: what is in the postgres logfile? After nohupping the command you can log out, log in again, and see if the background psql process is still running. Another way to accomplish the same thing would be to use `at`, also on the remote machine.

Comment: Thought I'd update for anyone else who goes through this. It turns out that the reason the restore was failing was that apparently three tables, which had unique constraints, had duplicate rows. When the power failed, there must have been an operation that was happening that allowed this or somehow allowed rows to be entered in all the up/down that followed. 
Once I located the suspect tables and deleted the duplicates, i was able to do a full reindex and do a full vacuum/analze